# Count how many rows have date within date range of each row for each ID Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where every row has a date range and an `ID` value.

I want to know for each row, how many other rows (that have the same `ID`) have a `date1` within the date range of that row.

Here's what I have tried:

```
import random
import string

test1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters[0:4]) for _ in range(3)) for n in range(100)],
    'date1':[pd.to_datetime(random.choice(['01-01-2018','05-01-2018','06-01-2018','08-01-2018','09-01-2018'])) + pd.DateOffset(int(np.random.randint(0, 100, 1))) for n in range(100)],
    'date2':[pd.to_datetime(random.choice(['06-01-2018','08-01-2018','09-01-2018'])) + pd.DateOffset(int(np.random.randint(201, 300, 1))) for n in range(100)]
})


count = []
test1['date2'] = test1['date2'] - pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='d')
for name, group in test1.groupby('ID'):
    df = group.loc[:,['date1','date2']].copy().stack().reset_index(name='c').set_index('c')
    df['count'] = df.groupby('level_0')...(I get stuck here)
    count = count.append(df['count'].to_list())
```

Then I get stuck here on how to determine how many of the other `date1`'s are within each date range.

So the end result should be a count for every row of how many other rows with the same `ID` had a `date1` in that date range.

Comment: If `id: abc` has 5 date ranges, the first being the index, and then next one is within the 1st date range, but then the other three are not in that index range.  But the fourth and fifth `date1` is in the range for the 3rd observation of 'abc'.  Do you count that as 3 or do you just look at the earliest occurrence of 'abc' and return 1?   Hope that makes sense...basically is each observation of 'abc' allowed to accumulate other 'abc' ranges, and sum up at the end, or are you worried only about the 1st observation of 'abc'?

Comment: @jtweeder For that situation, the first instance of `abc` would have a count of 2 since itself and the next one are in the date range. Then the 3rd observation of `abc` would be 3. If I understand you correctly. The index essentially shifts every time you obtain the count of that row.

Comment: Would you expect the final set to have two rows for 'abc' one with 2 and one with 3.  Or just one row for 'abc' with a 5?

Comment: @jtweeder the final set would have a count for every row. So there would be 5 counts. So the count for row 1 is 2, the count for row 2 would be the number of `date1`'s in that group that are within its date range, and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.merge` the `DataFrame` with itself on `ID`. Then compare if the `date` you brought over is between the two dates, excluding rows that merged with themselves.

```
import pandas as pd

m = test1.reset_index().merge(test1[['ID', 'date1']].reset_index(), on='ID')
#   index_x   ID    date1_x      date2  index_y    date1_y
#0        0  acb 2018-10-10 2019-01-24        0 2018-10-10
#1        0  acb 2018-10-10 2019-01-24       22 2018-10-09
#2        0  acb 2018-10-10 2019-01-24       47 2018-10-19
#3       22  acb 2018-10-09 2019-03-01        0 2018-10-10
#4       22  acb 2018-10-09 2019-03-01       22 2018-10-09

m['to_count'] = m.date1_y.ge(m.date1_x) & m.date1_y.le(m.date2) & (m.index_x != m.index_y)
m.groupby('index_x').to_count.sum()
#index_x
#0     1.0
#1     0.0
#2     2.0
#3     0.0
#     ... 
#97    1.0
#98    3.0
#99    1.0
```

---

Since this is based on the original index, you could assign it back with `test1['other_date1_between'] = m.groupby('index_x').to_count.sum()`.

```
print(test1.sort_values('ID').head(5))

     ID      date1      date2  other_date1_between
64  aaa 2018-07-21 2019-02-22                  0.0
86  aaa 2018-02-05 2019-05-10                  1.0
6   aab 2018-01-07 2019-04-09                  1.0
42  aab 2018-10-03 2019-03-17                  0.0
9   aac 2018-03-04 2019-02-24                  0.0
```