# Faster and python-native implementation of conditional sum (Vectorized)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to convert an excel SUMIF formula into python. However the way i am implemnting it using Pandas.apply() consume long time with high number of rows . Can someone help me with better vectorized implementation please .

```
def func1(x):
    
    res = data.loc[(( (x['Date'] -data['Date']).dt.days == 1) & (data['ID'] == x['ID'])), ['Stock'].sum()
    return res

data = pd.read_excel(settings['input_file'], sheet_name ="Data", usecols=range(0,10))
data['SUMIF']=data.apply(func1, axis=1)
```

Comment: Merge the DataFrame to itself `on=['ID']`, then exclude same row merges (by bringing along the index). This will allow you to do a vectorized check for all rows within 1 day of that row within `'ID'` and then you can sum, again as a vectorized operation. Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53506606/count-how-many-rows-have-date-within-date-range-of-each-row-for-each-id-pandas/53506993#53506993

Comment: @ALollz only the merge instruction took 22 seconds ! ```m = data.reset_index().merge(data[['ID', 'Date']].reset_index(), on='ID'```. When the original dataframe has around 13000 rows ...the merge result will have more than 300K rows

Comment: 300k isn't really that big of a dataset. Given that the following operations are all vectorized it's will mostly not be an issue unless you can't hold 300K rows, which seems small

Comment: @ALollz , the prob is not in the number of rows , but in the time taken by the merge operation. it took as much time as the inital method