# Efficient way to get the count of all values within a range of a group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53506993/7987118) question and the slightly modified solution works in the sample mode but runs out of memory for my full data set (with ~3GB worth of data).

I'm trying to find the count of all values within the range of a group (grouped by anchor):
The range formula is `y_val +- (anchor_val / 20)`.
Do note that `anchor_val` is consistent across all anchors, e.g.:

| ID | Anchor | y_val | anchor_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | ab | 80 | 40 |
| 13 | ab | 20 | 40 |
| 14 | abc | 80 | 50 |
| 15 | abc | 80 | 50 |
| 16 | ab | 81 | 40 |
| 17 | abd | 80 | 50 |

Which would result in:

| ID | Anchor | y_val | anchor_val | (anchor_val / 20) | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | ab | 80 | 40 | 2 | 1 |
| 13 | ab | 20 | 40 | 2 | 0 |
| 14 | abc | 80 | 50 | 2.5 | 1 |
| 15 | abc | 79 | 50 | 2.5 | 1 |
| 16 | ab | 81 | 40 | 2 | 1 |
| 17 | abd | 80 | 50 | 2.5 | 0 |

(I added the anchor_val/20 for clarity).

EDIT:

The current code that caused out of memory error:

```
 df["rule_8_comp_low"] = df["y_val"] - df["anchor_val"] / 20
df["rule_8_comp_high"] = df["y_val"] + df["anchor_val"] / 20
 m = df.reset_index().merge(
 df[["anchor_col", "y_val"]].reset_index(), on="anchor_col"
  )
 m["rule_8_to_count"] = (
 m.y_val_y.ge(m.rule_8_comp_low)
    & m.y_val_y.le(m.rule_8_comp_high)
     & (m.index_x != m.index_y)
  )
 df["y_val_between"] =  m.groupby("index_x").rule_8_to_count.sum()
```

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: @Marat updated the post

Comment: it's hard to see what's the difference between `df` and `m`, but dropping samples where `rule_8_to_count` is False should reduce memory footprint in groupby