# How to avoid memory issue when merging pandas dataframe on itself?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, out-of-memory

I’m running into a memory error that I think may have a workaround, but I can’t figure it out. (MemoryError: Unable to allocate 39.6 GiB for an array with shape (5309349043, ) and data type int64)

I’m using the [answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53506606/count-how-many-rows-have-date-within-date-range-of-each-row-for-each-id-pandas) to count observations between two dates. The method, however, makes the size of the dataframe explode at the point of creating the dataframe “m.”

To put this in perspective, I have about 12,000 IDs, each with over 1,000 observations (and the date offset is 6 months, as opposed to 14 days in the working example below).

Some example data and the code I used is below, though this isn’t necessary to understand the issue.

Would doing this on each ID and looping through work? If so, how could I do that?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['Begin'] = df.Date + pd.DateOffset(days=-14)
m = df.reset_index().merge(df[['ID', 'Date']].reset_index(), on='ID')
m['to_count'] = m.Date_x.ge(m.Date_y) & m.Begin.le(m.Date_y) 
df['dates_between'] = m.groupby('index_x').to_count.sum()
```

```
    ID      Date        Close
0   10000   2022-03-14  157.61
1   10000   2022-03-17  168.93
2   10000   2022-03-21  167.83
3   10000   2022-03-25  166.74
4   10000   2022-03-29  169.34
5   10000   2022-04-05  159.82
6   10000   2022-04-06  156.50
7   10000   2022-04-08  158.13
8   10000   2022-04-13  165.80
9   10000   2022-04-19  163.21
10  10000   2022-04-20  164.21
11  10000   2022-04-25  156.44
12  10000   2022-04-28  153.67
13  10000   2022-05-03  153.55
14  10000   2022-05-04  156.50
15  10000   2022-05-06  144.91
16  10000   2022-05-09  144.23
17  10000   2022-05-10  142.67
18  10000   2022-05-11  139.53
19  10000   2022-05-12  140.01
20  10000   2022-05-13  141.42
21  10000   2022-05-16  138.89
22  20000   2022-02-01  159.69
23  20000   2022-02-10  179.01
24  20000   2022-02-14  170.50
25  20000   2022-02-18  176.59
26  20000   2022-02-22  179.37
27  20000   2022-03-01  172.46
28  20000   2022-03-02  162.33
29  20000   2022-03-04  169.97
30  20000   2022-03-09  171.11
31  20000   2022-03-15  163.97
32  20000   2022-03-16  165.49
33  20000   2022-03-21  157.87
34  20000   2022-03-24  167.81
35  20000   2022-03-29  165.61
36  20000   2022-03-30  157.24
37  20000   2022-04-01  148.78
38  20000   2022-04-04  146.12
39  20000   2022-04-05  143.21
40  20000   2022-04-06  141.20
41  20000   2022-04-07  148.61
42  20000   2022-04-08  151.88
43  20000   2022-04-11  150.98
44  20000   2022-04-15  146.13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't need to merge here, you can take advantage of numpy broadcasting to compare each date to all dates of the same group in a vectorized way:

```
def to_count(sr):
    date = sr.values
    diff = date[:, None] - date
    mask = (pd.Timedelta('0D') <= diff) & (diff <= pd.Timedelta('14D'))
    return np.sum(mask, axis=1)

df['dates_between'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].transform(to_count)
```

If you prefer to reuse your code with `pd.DateOffset` instead of `pd.Timedelta`, you can also use:

```
def to_count(sr):
    date = sr.values
    begin = sr.sub(pd.DateOffset(days=14)).values
    mask = (begin[:, None] <= date) & (date <= date[:, None])
    return np.sum(mask, axis=1)

df['dates_between'] = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].transform(to_count)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       ID       Date   Close  dates_between
0   10000 2022-03-14  157.61              1
1   10000 2022-03-17  168.93              2
2   10000 2022-03-21  167.83              3
3   10000 2022-03-25  166.74              4
4   10000 2022-03-29  169.34              4
5   10000 2022-04-05  159.82              3
6   10000 2022-04-06  156.50              4
7   10000 2022-04-08  158.13              5
8   10000 2022-04-13  165.80              4
9   10000 2022-04-19  163.21              5
10  10000 2022-04-20  164.21              5
...
34  20000 2022-03-24  167.81              4
35  20000 2022-03-29  165.61              5
36  20000 2022-03-30  157.24              5
37  20000 2022-04-01  148.78              5
38  20000 2022-04-04  146.12              6
39  20000 2022-04-05  143.21              6
40  20000 2022-04-06  141.20              7
41  20000 2022-04-07  148.61              8
42  20000 2022-04-08  151.88              8
43  20000 2022-04-11  150.98              9
44  20000 2022-04-15  146.13              8
```

Comment: @Misha, does the script improve processing performance?

Comment: Wow! Yes, your script works splendidly. On over 12m obs (~12k IDs, ~1k dates/ID), your solution ran in less than a minute. Thank you for providing the option to use Dateoffset, as my actual application requires a six-month offset. I grabbed the data from a SQL table, so I considered using SQL, but your python script is really clean and fast.

Comment: Glad to read that :) Happy coding. For SQL, I think you should consider extracting the groups individually and process each group with Pandas?